# Is it possible to implement a class member functions in a different class

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following code. Would it be possible to derive class add from class math and declare the function sum, then derive a class from add called addNumbers which implements the function sum.

```
class math
{
public:
virtual int sum() = 0;
}

class add : public math
{
public:
int sum();
}

class addNumbers : public add
{
private:
int a, b;

public:
add::sum()
{ a + b}

}
```

Comment: Do you understand how polymorphism works?

Comment: Just drop the `int sum();` declaration from `class add`.

Comment: @rwols, it's clear that they don't :) Hence the question.

Comment: You can learn all about how that works from [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to derive class add from class math and declare the function sum, then derive a class from add called addNumbers which implements the function sum.

No.

`sum` has to be implemented in `add` if it is declared the way you have it. Otherwise, you should see a linker error.

If `add` does not have sufficient information to implement `sum`, don't declare `sum` in `add`. Declare and define it in `addNumbers`.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

Use

```
class add : public math
{
   // Add whatever is needed for this class
}

class addNumbers : public add
{
   private:
      int a, b;

   public:
      int sum()
      { 
         return (a + b)
      }

};
```

Comment: Well, leaving out the declaration it's just transparent.

Comment: How should I declare my sum function so that it works like I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `sum` function in the `addNumbers` . 
the `sum` function declare in math class virtually . however you wasn't define `sum` function in `add` virtually but it is virtual . Thus you can define/implement `sum` in the `addNumbers` and it will be overwrite on previous declaration in `add` Class.